# Autoresize view to fit multiline label with dynamic text length

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a `UIView` containing a `UILabel` made in an Interface Builder .xib file. The label text is set from code and I want the `UIView` and `UILabel` to resize to fit the text using auto layout.

Label configuration:

- Pinned width 320
- Number of lines 0
- Leading space to superview 0
- Bottom space to superview 0
- Trailing space to superview 0

The view is loaded like this:

```
MyView *myView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
myView.myLabel.text = @"My short or long text";
```

and I use it as a table header:

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:myView];
```

The view does not resize, it stays one line truncated with ... at the end. How do I get it to resize?

I tried increasing vertical content hugging and content resistance for the label, I tried adding a low priority height constraint, I tried `setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth`, all without luck.

Note: This is a simplified example. I will need more elements in the view, and I would like to avoid calculating every coordinate manually based on the label's `sizeWithFont`. It's my understanding that auto layout should be the holy grail for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(maxWidthOfYourLabel, 9999);
UIFont *myFont = label.font;
CGSize myStringSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:myFont constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]; 
label.frame = CGRectMake (label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y, myStringSize.width, myStringSize.height);

yourView.height = label.height;
```

This is the only way i know and this involves `sizeWithFont:`

Comment: Not really the answer I was looking for, because with multiple elements in the view you will have to manually update the frame of the superview with the sum of all element heights + margins. There must be some way to make auto layout resize automatically using the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt UITableView will play nicely with your view if you are resizing its header with autolayout. The way we work with dynamic-sized table headers (or footers) is like this:

1. Compute and resize the header view's frame.
2. Re-set the header via `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myView;`

Step 2 is the key. You have to set `tableHeaderView` again even if the same view will be applied. I understand that having to play with frames in an autolayout paradigm is very ugly, but you may not have to if you find the proper method to put `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myView;`.

Answer (score 0):

I just come across the same problem like you.
What I do is like this:

```
//Init headerView from nib file
//Set the content to show
[headerView setupWith:somethingToShow];              

headerView.height = [headerView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```